# qplot | ggplot | R data Visualization | group by

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization, jqplot

Please help and review.

Using dataset msleep, plot a qplot against bodywt and sleep_total factors, and add a line using geo_smooth.
Use qplot to draw a line applying a linear regression model to remove the standard error.
Group by vore.
Separate the model into multi-facets by vore.

***names(msleep):"name" "genus" "vore" "order" "conservation" "sleep_total"  "sleep_rem" "sleep_cycle" "awake"  "brainwt" "bodywt"***

```
***

qplot(log(bodywt),sleep_total,data=msleep)+geom_smooth()
    qplot(log(bodywt),sleep_total,data=msleep)+geom_smooth(method = "lm",se=F)
    qplot(log(bodywt),sleep_total,data=msleep,color=vore)+geom_smooth(method = "lm",se=F)
    qplot(log(bodywt),sleep_total,data=msleep)+geom_smooth(method = "lm",se=F)+facet_grid(.~vore)
```

---

Comment: What error or problem are you facing?

Comment: this is an assignment in katacode. not able to pass the assignment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ggplot` like

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(msleep, aes(x = log(bodywt), y= sleep_total))+
  geom_point()+
  geom_smooth(method = "lm",se=F)+facet_grid(.~vore, scales = "free")
```

[image]
Without facet

```
ggplot(msleep, aes(x = log(bodywt), y= sleep_total, color=vore))+
  geom_point()+
  geom_smooth(method = "lm",se=F)
```

[image]